# Redirection to custom url via nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem with redirection. I have a small **nodejs/express** app that should redirect to external URL with form's input values after submiting form.

*index.html*

```
<form method="POST" action="https://192.0.2.1/abc.html">
    <input name="name"/>
    <input name="email"/>
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

It's only goes to `https://192.0.2.1/abc.html` without inputs' values. Please, help.

Comment: Can you provide some further details? Is 192.0.2.1 the nodejs server? Where is index.html hosted? Have you written a function that should receive the form's input value?

Comment: What mechanism are you using in the HTML file to output the result?

Comment: Are you looking for `method="get"` instead of `post`?

Comment: Your best bet would be to look into: `http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals`

Comment: @AaronUllal @Tom @str @VladNeacsu I think I'm totally noob in programming yet, but here my explanation :)

I have nodeJS app with express. Device, router f.e., redirects users to my app. User should enter his credentials and after pushing SUBMIT, and then app must pass his inputs to `https://192.0.2.1/abc.html`, that is router's page, that excepts user inputs and show him is that information correct. So my app only redirects user back with his inputs via POST request

Comment: @AleksMaksiuta Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example

I wrote a working example of what you're describing:

```
'use strict';
var host = '127.0.0.1', port = 3333;
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.type('html').end(`
    <form method="POST" action="http://${host}:${port}/abc.html">
    <input name="name"/>
    <input name="email"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="http://${host}:${port}/def.html">
    <input name="name"/>
    <input name="email"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `);
});
app.post('/abc.html', (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.name, email = req.body.email;
  res.redirect(`http://${host}:${port}/ghi.html?name=${name}&email=${email}`);
});
app.post('/def.html', (req, res) => {
  res.type('html').end(`
    <p>Name: ${req.body.name}</p>
    <p>Email: ${req.body.email}</p>
  `);
});
app.get('/ghi.html', (req, res) => {
  res.type('html').end(`
    <p>Name: ${req.query.name}</p>
    <p>Email: ${req.query.email}</p>
  `);
});
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Listening on http://${host}:${port}/`));
```

### Running

You need to install `express` and `body-parser`:

```
npm install express body-parser
```

And run with:

```
node app.js
```

### Two forms

The first form correctly passes the parameters via POST method. The `POST /abc.html` handler has access to them and sends a redirect to a custom URL of the form: `/ghi.html?name=xxx&email=yyy` - the target of the redirection displays those values in HTML and you can see them in the address bar as well.

The second form doesn't redirect but directly displays the parameters, so that you could better see what's going on. It's also useful to open the Developer Console in your browser and observe the Network activity while you are clicking the form buttons.

### Explanation

It's not entirely clear from your example what can be wrong in your code, but I hope that showing you an example code that works will help you diagnose the problem in your implementation.

What you have to keep in mind is that for GET requests with parameters passed in the query string, you access them as:

```
req.query.name
req.query.email
```

and for the POST requests with parameters passed in the request body, you have to use `body-parser` middleware and then you can access them with:

```
req.body.name
req.body.email
```

### Requests overview

The requests that take place here are:

1. You access http://127.0.0.1:3333/ and get the HTML with two forms
2. You enter email `aaa` for name and `bbb` for email and submit the first form
3. Your browser sends a POST request to `/abc.html` with `name=aaa&email=bbb` in the body
4. The server sends a `302 Found` response with `Location: http://127.0.0.1:3333/ghi.html?name=aaa&email=bbb` header
5. Your browser sends a GET request to: `/ghi.html?name=aaa&email=bbb`
6. The server sends a `200 OK` response with HTML including the parameters

Comment: @AleksMaksiuta That's good to hear that it helped you. You can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that others will see that this question has an accepted answer when searching this topic.